# Is the cross product a tensor or pseudotensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, cross-product

I am confused as to the tensor nature of the cross product. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what I'm reading. But I seem to be getting conflicting messages.

Comment: The cross product is a pseudovector. Where do you get a contradicting message?

Comment: Just look at the other answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of 'tensor' is often different to physicists and mathematicians. To a mathematician a tensor is a multilinear object - an element of a tensor product space. A cross product is a vector, therefore it's a tensor.

To a physicist it's particularly an object which transforms tensorially under changes of coordinates, ie, with one copy of the coordinate transformation matrix per index. A cross product doesn't *transform* like a vector in the standard $(x,y,z)$ basis, but instead like a thing called a pseudovector.

Pseudovectors and pseudotensors can also be *represented* as antisymmetric elements of a tensor product space. Cross products act like antisymmetric elements of $ \mathbb{R}^3 \otimes \mathbb{R}^3 $, which is a tensor product space, and when written in this space (with basis $(x \wedge y, y \wedge z, z \wedge x)$) they *do* transform tensorially. It's just when you write them as elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that they don't.

The coordinates of $a \times b$ are given by: $a_i b_j - a_j b_i$, which has two indices and therefore must transform with two copies of a coordinate transformation. However, when you map write pseudovectors as vectors, you map 'ij' to a *single* index ($x \times y \rightarrow z$)  using the [Hodge star operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator), even though it should still transform somehow with two copies of the coordinate transformation. Hence, it does not transform 'tensorially'.

[Exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) clears this all up. Cross products should be written in the basis $(x \wedge y, y \wedge z, z \wedge x)$, and transform indices with $\wedge^2 R$ if coordinates transform as $R$.

See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624411/mathematicians-tensors-vs-physicists-tensors) question.

Comment: Where can I read about the cross product from the mathematician's point of view as an element of $\mathbb{R} ^3 \otimes \mathbb{R}^3$. Why is the physicist's "transforms tensorially under change of coordinates" is different from the how mathematician's tensor behaves. For example isn't $e_1\otimes e_2=(a_{11}e_1' + a_{21}e_2'+ a_{31}e_3') \otimes (a_{12}e_1' + a_{22}e_2'+a_{32}e_3')$ and expanding out the same as expressing how it "transforms under coordinate change".

Comment: Wikipedia on [pseudovector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector) has a lot to say about it.

Comment: Basically:

The problem is that $x \wedge y = x \otimes y - y \otimes x$ transforms with two copies of a coordinate change $P$ (via $P \otimes P$). But if you map it to $z$, you might try to change it with _one_ copy.

Similarly, the indexes of a bivector $a_{ij} e^i \wedge e^j$ should transform with two copies of $P$ (because they're tensor products, really). But if you write them as $a_k e^k$, as a vector, then you might wrongly try to transform them with one copy of $P$. The coordinate should still change like this: $(P^{-1})^i_m (P^{-1})^j_n a_{ij}$.

Comment: Consider what would happen if you computed the cross product $\vec{v} = x \times y = z$ and then transformed it with a transformation that mapped $y \rightarrow x$ and fixes $x$ and $z$. The value $\vec{v}$ _should_ become 0 (because $x \times x = 0$), but your transformation fixed $z$, so if you wrote $\vec{v} = z$ you would leave it unchanged.

If you instead wrote $\vec{v} = x \wedge y$, then the transformation would map $\vec{v} \rightarrow x \wedge x = 0$.

Comment: So what I think I understand is that the cross product as a first order tensor (a vector) doesn't work. But as a second order tensor it truly is a tensor. But I still don't understand what you mean by "A physicists' pseudotensor is a subtype of a mathematician's tensor".

Comment: Mathematicians aren't usually as concerned with how things change under changes of coordinates. Technically $\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = (a_y b_z - a_z b_y) \hat{x} + (a_z b_x - a_x b_z) \hat{y} + (a_x b_y - a_y b_x) \hat{z}$ _is_ a vector, which is a type of tensor. It's only when you talk about how it changes coordinates that you realize it doesn't change 'tensorially', because it 'actually' transforms as a second order tensor . In physics that means it doesn't count as a tensor, so they call it something else.

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624411/mathematicians-tensors-vs-physicists-tensors) for bunch more discussion.

Comment: So are you saying then that physicists call the cross product a first order pseudotensor (or pseudovector) because they use the first order form of the cross product rather than the second order tensor form?

Comment: Yes, specifically because they often reserve the word 'tensor' for things that transform in the regular way (with one copy of the transformation matrix for each index).

Comment: Just to be clear the cross product is a second order contravariant tensor and not a second order covariant tensor

Comment: Note we are talking about the cross product of (polar) vectors here. That's an axial (a.k.a. pseudo-) vector. But the cross product of a polar vector with an axial vector is actually a polar vector. One such example from physics is the force on a moving charge in a magnetic field, $\vec{F} = q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}.$ Here $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{v}$ are polar vectors, but $\vec{B}$ is an axial vector.

Answer (score 0):

The cross product is a bilinear vector valued mapping hence is a tensor.

Comment: What kind of tensor? How many indices does it have?

Comment: @md2perpe it is THE bilinear map $\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ given by $(v,w)\mapsto v\times w$

Comment: @janmarqz But isn't there suppose to be something about flipping signs incorrectly for the cross product on change of basis that don't preserve orientation?

Comment: @user782220 tell us what definition do you want to use?

Comment: give an eye to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra

Comment: @janmarqz so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudotensor says that a pseudotensor is a generalization of a Pseudovector. And I read that the cross product is a pseudovector. Is a pseudovector not a pseudotensor but instead a tensor so there is no contradiction?